# how to find in which line the string is in csv file in c

Tags: c, string, file, char, fread

i need to detect in which line the string is in csv file in c..
ive tried with counting the '\n' times until we get to our string place...
but its always printing that's in the second line, no matter what is the input.
its like its not really reading the file and copy the text to buff string...
and also the strcpsn not working

```
printf("\nEnter the string you want to search: ");
getchar();
myFgets(str, LEN); //getting input

file = fopen(adr, "r"); //opening file
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Eror opening first file\n");
    return 1;
}

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

char* buff = (char*)calloc(strlen(str), sizeof(char));
if (buff == NULL)
{
    printf("Allocation eror!\n");
    return 1;
}
fread(buff, sizeof(char), len, file);
seek = strcspn(buff, str); //checking where is the string starting
while (lineSeek <= seek)
{
    ch = fgetc(file);
    if (ch == '\n')
    {
        line++;
        lineSeek = ftell(file);
    }
}

printf("its on %d line", line + 1);
```

Comment: You have a stewpot with `fseek` and `calloc` and `fread` and `feof` and `fgetc`. If this is a text file, stick to text-based functions. You read each line with `fgets` and check if it contains your string with `strstr` until you have found it. I suggest starting again, sorry, with a nice long `char[]` buffer to read each line into.

Comment: Why are you using the return code from`feof` to determine how many characters to read from the file initially?

Comment: fixed that... updated. still not working...

Comment: Now `buff` is the size of your input string, but you read the whole file into it.

Comment: Once you've read the whole file into memory, why are you still accessing the file?

Comment: You don't need `calloc()`, use `malloc()`. Also, you are allocating too little space you need one extra byte for the `null` terminator. And the worse part, is that you can't read the whole line into such a small buffer, in principle if the line will contain your string it has to be larger or equal in length to your string. Finally, don't cast `calloc()` to `char *` or use `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: in ch? i need to do `ch = fgetc(buff)` or with `strchar`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be making it harder than it needs to be. You can use `strstr` to search each line as it is read for your search term. You can use `strchr` to confirm that the line contains a `'\n'` before incrementing your line count (to protect against a *short-read* using `fgets`.

Putting that together, all that is needed is the following. Note the code takes the search term as the first argument and then the file name to search as the second (if no second argument is given, it will read from `stdin` by default):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 512 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "insufficient input, usage: %s term [file (stdin)]\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t found = 0, line = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    char *term = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        if (strstr (buf, term)) {       /* test for term  */
            found = 1; break;           /* set found flag */
        }
        if (strchr (buf, '\n')) line++; /* increment line */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    if (found) printf ("'%s' found on line %zu.\n", term, line + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** if you want to match *whole-fields*, you can tokenize each line with `strsep` before comparing each token with the search term. If *empty-fields* are not an issue, `strtok` can be used.

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/search.csv
my,dog,has,fleas
the,other,one,doesn't
the,cat,has,none
the,snake,is,done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/searchcsv cat <dat/search.csv
'cat' found on line 3.
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.